# How can I partition a table in BigQuery by date when the data type is integer?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

At the moment I have a table with an integer field where a date value comes in YYYYMMDD format, the objective is to be able to partition the table by this field without the need to create another field or column

Do you have a sample code for partitioning?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: BigQuery partitions on integers.  In fact, a section of the documentation is devoted to this topic:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-integer-range-partitions.  The documentation is a good place to strt.

Comment: it is correct, but the problem here is that it is not possible more than 10 thousand partitions

Comment: . . 10,000 days is about 27 years.  In any case, the documentation is quite clear on how to use integer partitions and on the limits of partitioning.  I think you should delete this question.

Comment: perfect, can you show me some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an integer based partition table, One has to use GENERATE_ARRAY function.

```
RANGE_BUCKET(<int64_column>, GENERATE_ARRAY(start_expression, end_expression[, step_expression]))
```

> Considering a field like date (formatted as YYYYMMDD),sequentially
> generated 10000 numbers range(20200101-20210100) start from 20200101
> would store around one year dates from (2020-01-01 to 2020-12-31)
> using total partition 1131 (30/31 per 100 partitions) and other
> partitions range (20201232-20210100) would not be used since those not
> valid formatted date.

Now coming to answer, if you have dates around for a year use below code or one which is
also documented.

```
CREATE TABLE DATASET.T_TABLE_PAR
PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(COD_DATE,GENERATE_ARRAY(20200101,20201231,1))
AS
SELECT  COD_DATE,CLUSTER FROM  DATASET.T_TABLE
```

And I believe you have more than a year date data. So answer is, there is no direct way you can do that (*'without the need to create another field or column'*) .

I can think of a work around if you are willing to store changed data (20200201 as 20200132).

```
--This function does the change, actual date to partition number and vice-versa, change start and end date as per your need.
create temp function date_get_set(date_code int64,type string)
as(
(
SELECT case when type='get' then a
            when type='set' then b end
          from  (
SELECT cast(FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", example) as int64) a,
       20200100+row_number() over(order by example asc) b
from UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', '2021-12-31')) AS example)
where (case when  type='get' then b
            when type='set' then a end) = date_code
)

);
select date_get_set(20200132,'get') get_the_date,date_get_set(20200201,'set') set_the_partiontion
```

Output of above select :

[image]

Now create the above function (Persistent- remove temp) and partition table as below.

```
CREATE TABLE DATASET.T_TABLE_PAR
PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(COD_DATE,GENERATE_ARRAY(20200101,20202020,1))
AS
SELECT  DATASET.date_get_set(COD_DATE,'set') COD_DATE,CLUSTER FROM  DATASET.T_TABLE
```

To prune the query and read right date value use the function.

```
SELECT  DATASET.date_get_set(COD_DATE,'get'),CLUSTER 
FROM  DATASET.T_TABLE
where  COD_DATE = DATASET.date_get_set(20200201,'set')
```

> So two disadvantaged, Function may increases some computational cost and the
> changed data(a view on the table would help further) . :)